# pyqt custom item delegate for qtablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a QTableWidget with 5 columns in it, how do I set all items on column 2 to be a QProgressBar?

I tried something like:

```
self.downloads_table = QtGui.QTableWidget(0, 5)
self.downloads_table.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, DownloadDelegate(self))
```

Where DownloadDelegate is:

```
class DownloadDelegate(QItemDelegate):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(DownloadDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

  def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    return QProgressBar(parent)
```

But the progress bar doesn't show up at all. Any idea?

Comment: I just found QTableWidget.setCellWidget(), works like charm. :)

Comment: Then it would be nice if you wrote that as an answer, and accept it (you can accept your own answer; that will even give you the self-learner badge), so this information is here for the next guy looking for it.

Comment: I am that next guy looking for it.. @Marconi can you post your answer  please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marconi said,

```
QTableWidget.setCellWidget(row, column, QWidget)
```

adds a QWidget into the cell at (row, column) and gives it the QTableWidget as parent.

e.g. something along these lines:

```
table = QTableWidget(1, 3)
item1 = QTableWidgetItem("foo")
comboBox = QComboBox()
checkBox = QCheckBox()
table.setItem(0,0,item1)
table.setCellWidget(0,1,comboBox)
table.setCellWidget(0,2,checkBox)
```

will give you a `1x3` table with "foo" in `cell 0,0`, a `QComboBox` in `cell 0,1` and a `QCheckBox` in `cell 0,2`.

Answer (score 0):

The model must return `itemEditable` in `flags()`